# looping through a placeholder to create a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to automatically change the names for missing values for  pandas column based on an if condition, preferably using a 'string_name_number'. The numbers should start from one and end at the last missing value. I have decided to set my loop as follows to select data from a string.

However the results (df2) from the missing column remain the same. As follows; - respondent i, jakson, respondent i, respondent i, jane, respondent i, mary,     ...

I expected to see the following results (df2); - respondent 1, jakson, respondent 2, respondent 3, jane, respondent 4, mary,     ...

Please assist.

```
import pandas as pd  

df = pd.read_csv('232 responses.csv', sep=',',header=0, parse_dates=True, 
                 index_col='Timestamp')

missing_rows_list = list(range(0, len (df)))

for i in missing_rows_list:
    i = 1
    df2 = [df['Name (optional)']\
           .replace(np.nan, 'respondent {d[i]}'\
           .format(d=missing_rows_list)) if pd.isnull(df['Name (optional)']) \
            else df['Name (optional)'] == word in df['Name (optional)']]
    i += 1
```

Comment: Before you seek any further advice: `df['Name (optional)'].isnull` is _not_ a method call, but a reference to a method. This expression is always `True`.

Comment: Let me check on it and get back to you.

Comment: Adjusted to pd.isnull(df['Name (optional)']), I hope that is a method call.

Comment: See my code below. If you need some modifications please let me know

Comment: Thanks alot it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should handel it and is a more convenient approach:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"a":["test1","test2","test3","test4",np.NAN],"b":["test5",np.NAN,"test7",np.NAN,"test9"]})

#Create the respondent + inex number format --> you can also save this in an extra df column if you like
a=["respondent"]*len(df.index)
b=list(df.index)
c=["{0}{1}".format(a_,b_)for a_,b_ in list(zip(a,b))]

#Replace the missing values
for i in df.columns:
    mask = df[i].isnull()
    df[i].mask(mask,c, inplace=True)

print(df)



           a          b
0      test1      test5
1      test2  response1
2      test3      test7
3      test4  response3
4  response4      test9
```